# Xamarin for Android/iOS development

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am planning to use Xamarin platform for a big scale mobile app for iOS and Android. As I am a C# developer so I think the learning curve will be small. Can somebody guide what are the limitations of this framework which can affect app performance or development. I want to consult someone who has already used it and seen results before making a decision. My app will have lots of user and transactions, maps, notifications, access to device contents/services.

Please also suggest in which forum I can ask this question if this is not correct forum.

Comment: Xamarin has its own forum.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're working natively in both environments, almost almost no limitation will be found because the highly escalvel Xamarin and fully supported all the native API of each platform. Using the XamarinForms you will have an experience almost never seen before, as it is a way to share about 99% of the code for all platforms (iOS, Android, WP).

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to best practices like watching your memory allocations or cleaning up stuff properly you won't ran into limitations that a Java or Objective-C counterpart wouldn't face.

Using Xamarin.iOS and/ or Xamarin.Android you are as close to the platform as possible because Xamarin "just" provides wrapper classes around the native api.

With Xamarin.Forms it is a little bit different. There are limitations at using a map or access device specific features. While there are ways to over come this limitations, for instance you can integrate a native map through custom renderers, I also experienced some memory issues I do not see by using Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android.

Hope that helps.